# python3 relative import not working: ImportError: cannot import name 'gmail'

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I understand that relative import has to be explicit in python 3, but i can't figure this one out.

I have one directory called work and files main.py and gmail.py

In main.py, I used to have "import gmail" in python 2

I just used 2to3, and this line was changed to "from . import gmail"

```
user@ubuntu:~/work$ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import gmail
ImportError: cannot import name 'gmail'
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, when I do "python gmail.py", it works fine.

```
$ cat main.py 
from . import gmail

$ cat gmail.py 
print('test')
```

======================================
Ok I found that this works
    $ cat main.py 
    import gmail

So why did 2to3 change this to something that does not work? 
And why do people say use "from . import gmail" when actually "import gmail" works?

Comment: For anyone encountering this issue, the solution is plain old `import gmail`